# How to force https responses from Android Retrofit GET calls

Tags: android, https, retrofit2

i am investigating the api endpoints from https://openexchangerates.org/ in my current hobby android application.

i am making use of two endpoints

```
https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json
```

and

```
https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json
```

the call i make to currencies.json works fine as shown here

```
0001 https://openexchangerates.org/currencies.json
0001 0.001 callStart
--> GET https://openexchangerates.org/currencies.json
Accept: application/json
--> END GET
0001 0.010 proxySelectStart
0001 0.011 proxySelectEnd
0001 0.012 dnsStart
0001 0.052 dnsEnd
0001 0.061 connectStart
0001 0.174 secureConnectStart
0001 0.658 secureConnectEnd
0001 0.660 connectEnd
0001 0.661 connectionAcquired
0001 0.663 requestHeadersStart
0001 0.664 requestHeadersEnd
0001 0.864 responseHeadersStart
0001 0.864 responseHeadersEnd
0001 0.866 responseBodyStart
0001 0.867 responseBodyEnd
0001 0.871 requestHeadersStart
0001 0.872 requestHeadersEnd
0001 0.984 responseHeadersStart
0001 0.984 responseHeadersEnd
<-- 200 OK https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json (982ms)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 13:04:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 13:45:36 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
0001 0.988 responseBodyStart
0001 0.988 responseBodyEnd
{
  "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
  "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
```

however the call to latest.json has this "feature"

```
0002 https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
0002 0.000 callStart
--> GET https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
Accept: application/json
--> END GET
0002 0.003 connectionAcquired
0002 0.004 requestHeadersStart
0002 0.005 requestHeadersEnd
0002 0.008 responseFailed
0002 0.010 connectionReleased
0002 0.011 connectStart
0002 0.142 secureConnectStart
0002 0.554 secureConnectEnd
0002 0.555 connectEnd
0002 0.555 connectionAcquired
0002 0.556 requestHeadersStart
0002 0.558 requestHeadersEnd
0002 0.962 responseHeadersStart
0002 0.963 responseHeadersEnd
0002 0.964 responseBodyStart
0002 0.965 responseBodyEnd
0002 0.968 connectionReleased
0002 0.969 proxySelectStart
0002 0.970 proxySelectEnd
0002 0.971 dnsStart
0002 0.992 dnsEnd
0002 0.994 connectStart
0002 1.110 connectEnd
0002 1.111 connectionAcquired
0002 1.112 requestHeadersStart
0002 1.114 requestHeadersEnd
0002 1.224 responseHeadersStart
0002 1.225 responseHeadersEnd
<-- 200 OK http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg (1224ms)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 13:07:34 GMT
Etag: W/"3c46229cfde06a956ce1b6198e484341"
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 13:00:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
0002 1.229 responseBodyStart
0002 1.230 responseBodyEnd
```

why is the response http when i am targetting the https endpoint?
is there anything i can do to correct this?

this endpoint works fine from a browser, however when i configure retrofit to NOT follow redirects i get this response

```
0002 https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
0002 0.000 callStart
--> GET https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--> END GET
0002 0.002 connectionAcquired
0002 0.003 requestHeadersStart
0002 0.004 requestHeadersEnd
0002 0.155 responseHeadersStart
0002 0.156 responseHeadersEnd
0002 0.157 responseBodyStart
0002 0.157 responseBodyEnd
<-- 301 Moved Permanently https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg (157ms)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 14:19:31 GMT
Location: http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
<-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
0002 0.161 connectionReleased
0002 0.161 callEnd
```

which appears to identify the culprit as

```
<-- 301 Moved Permanently https://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg (157ms)

Location: http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg
```

Comment: But why is that a problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: Think this has nothing to do with Retrofit and all with the redirect from the webserver. Try this url in a browser.

Comment: @blackapps whats wrong is i have to allow CLEARTEXT traffic in my network config xml file

Comment: Pretty strange you did not mention that in your post. How does one write a post,?

Comment: A server may try to redirect from https to http but a client should never allow it, at least by default. I can't be sure what is happening here but I don't think the client is following the insecure http redirect.